# How to make the for loop execute each line of the .txt file at a time in a function

Tags: python, automation

I have this bot for whatsapp made using selenium, it identifies the browser fields, types the group name and does what the script says. The problem is that when clicking on the Whatsapp Web search box the bot is typing "Test1Test2Test3" instead of typing "Test1", find the whatsapp conversation and run the rest of the code, then repeat the same process with "Test2" and "Test3"
In the txt file I ordered Test 1, 2 and 3 one under the other

The code:

```
class NajaBot:
    if str(gma()) == userMac:
        print("Cadastro, ok")
        if check_internet():
            print("Internet, ok")
            if dia < diaVenc and mes <= mesVenc and ano == anoVenc:
                print("Validade, ok")

                def sendMsg(self, order):
                    if order == "Ok":
                        self.mensagem = clipboard.paste()
                        fileGroups = open('grupos.txt', 'r')
                        read = fileGroups.read()
                        self.grupos_ou_pessoas = [read.splitlines()]
                        fileGroups.close()
                        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
                        options.add_argument('lang=pt-br')
                        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
                            executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
                        print("Cadastro, ok")
                        print("mensagem enviada!")
                        self.driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
                        time.sleep(50)
                        print("pesquisando nomes")
                        for grupos in self.grupos_ou_pessoas:
                            caixa_de_pesquisa = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                                f'//div[@title="Caixa de texto de pesquisa"]')
                            caixa_de_pesquisa.click()
                            time.sleep(2)
                            caixa_de_pesquisa.send_keys(grupos)
                            time.sleep(2)
                            campo_grupo = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                                f"//span[@title='{grupos}']")
                            time.sleep(3)
                            campo_grupo.click()
                            chat_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                                "//div[@title='Mensagem']")
                            time.sleep(3)
                            chat_box.click()
                            chat_box.send_keys(self.mensagem)
                            botao_enviar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                                "//span[@data-icon='send']")
                            time.sleep(3)
                            botao_enviar.click()


bot = NajaBot()
bot.sendMsg("No")
```

The debug error:

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //span[@title='['Teste 1', 'Teste 2', 'Teste 3']'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//span[@title='['Teste 1', 'Teste 2', 'Teste 3']']' is not a valid XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the problem is this line

```
                        self.grupos_ou_pessoas = [read.splitlines()]
```

and it should be

```
                        self.grupos_ou_pessoas = read.splitlines()
```

the way you had it, `grupos_ou_pessoas` was a list containing a single list, which contained the three lines. You want, I think, just a flat list with three strings

Comment: The problem was exactly this bro, thank you very much!

Comment: @Lipe excellent! consider an upvote and accepting the answer, since it answered your question